# Deploying Rails database.yml giving weird error messages

Tags: mysql, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I'm deploying with Capistrano, Rails 4 + Passenger + nginx, in a centOS machine.

I'm linking database.yml through `app/shared/config/database.yml`. I was working with postgres, but I have changed to mysql2. I have managed to successfully run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` so far.

Trying to access my droplet, the following thing appears:

```
Mysql2::Error Unsupported charset: '"UTF8"

Rails.root: /home/deploy/apps/my_app/releases/20140515022908`
```

The thing is, I already removed the utf8 part from the database.yml file, it looks currently like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: something
  password: 
  database: asdf_development

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: something_else
  password: 
  database: asdf_test

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: asdf_production
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: pass
  host: localhost
```

I have restarted the mysqld service just to be sure, but the error keeps showing. Any idea why is this happening?

EDIT: database.yml is linked

```
[deploy@my_app config]$ ls -la
total 48
drwxrwxr-x  6 deploy deploy 4096 May 14 22:29 .
drwxrwxr-x 11 deploy deploy 4096 May 14 22:29 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 deploy deploy  966 May 14 22:28 application.rb
-rw-rw-r--  1 deploy deploy  171 May 14 22:28 boot.rb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy deploy   55 May 14 22:29 database.yml -> /home/deploy/apps/my_app/shared/config/database.yml
drwxrwxr-x  2 deploy deploy 4096 May 14 22:28 deploy
-rw-rw-r--  1 deploy deploy 1504 May 14 22:28 deploy.rb
-rw-rw-r--  1 deploy deploy  155 May 14 22:28 environment.rb
drwxrwxr-x  2 deploy deploy 4096 May 14 22:28 environments
drwxrwxr-x  2 deploy deploy 4096 May 14 22:28 initializers
drwxrwxr-x  2 deploy deploy 4096 May 14 22:28 locales
-rw-rw-r--  1 deploy deploy 1818 May 14 22:28 routes.rb
-rw-rw-r--  1 deploy deploy  656 May 14 22:28 schedule.rb
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't copied the file instead of linking it?

Comment: Positive. Added further data.

Comment: try use this instead https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql.